Draw shape using html/css
Need to create a shape attached.
Remove the icon border of an specific position and move that in the top left of the rectangle using css and html with bootstrap5. image is not positioning correctly inside the rectangle.


.node {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green background color */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 80px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  padding-left: 50px;
  /* Space for the image */
}

.node-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  /* Half of the circle's diameter */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.node-image i {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.node-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
<div class="node">
  <div class="node-image">
    <i class="bi bi-box"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="node-text">Name</div>
</div>





While this might be possible, one needs to keep in mind that neither HTML nor CSS are graphical drawing programs and one should use better tools to do such things such as SVG

Move to circle to top and add border with same color and it will look how you aspect. Below is working example of same.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainDiv {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.node {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green background color */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 80px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  padding-left: 50px;
  /* Space for the image */
}

.node-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  /* Half of the circle's diameter */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -14px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 5px solid #54b059;
}

.node-image i {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.node-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="node">
    <div class="node-image">
      <i class="bi bi-box"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="node-text">Name</div>
  </div>
</div>




Add border to the circle and apply box-shadow to the top and left side of it using box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0); and border: 6px solid #4caf50; to the circle to achieve your result.


.node {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green background color */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 80px;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  padding-left: 50px;
  /* Space for the image */
  margin-top: 5%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.node-image {
  position: absolute;
  left: -7px;
  /* Half of the circle's diameter */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -7px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px solid #4caf50;
}

.node-image i {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.node-text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
    
<div class="node" style="margin-left: 10%;">
  <div class="node-image">
    <i class="bi bi-box"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="node-text">Name</div>
</div>



